# Display passed tests while they run with latest NUnit3TestAdapter version 4+

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm having a silly problem, with Nunit3TestAdapter version 3 under dotnet 5, I could see tests while they were passing, with the execution time detailed, the "Passed Test1" in the following transcript, as long as verbosity was set to at least normal:

```
$ dotnet test -v normal
[...]
NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution complete
  Passed Test1 [21 ms]
  Passed Test2 [< 1 ms]

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 2
     Passed: 2
```

I recently upgraded to dotnet 6 and nunit adapter 4.2.0, and now I'm unable to display the detailed output, even with the higher (detailed) verbosity:

```
$ dotnet test -v detailed
[...]
Test run for /tmp/nunit-repro/bin/Debug/net6.0/nunit-repro.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     2, Skipped:     0, Total:     2, Duration: 24 ms - /tmp/nunit-repro/bin/Debug/net6.0/nunit-repro.dll (net6.0)
```

I've been looking around for some time now and cannot find a relevant configuration option. Am I missing something?

Having integration test suites made of hundreds of tests and taking several minutes to pass, it's quite frustrating to have no visual progress whatsoever, not knowing if things are running or hanging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone found the solution for me, add `-l "console;verbosity=detailed"`:

```
dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=detailed"
```